# Pi 3 has Wi-Fi country code reset problems

Tags: wifi

My two day old (March 26, 2016) Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, running Jessey OS 8, can't reset the Wi-Fi country code. The one I have came from Canakit with the system already loaded on a Micro SD. So, I don't know if it's all OS 8's fault or just a problem from CanaKit. I've seen the problem posted many times, therefore, it's probably an OS 8 problem.

If you go to **Preferences -> Configure**, there are four drop down menus. You can easily configure three of them. But, the last one: Set **Wi-Fi Country Code** drop down menu does not work. It gives you a country list with the option **AD Andora** already set. It will not allow you to select any other country: my case, US. No matter how many times you try or reboot, it still comes up AD Andora.

As a result, the Wi-Fi routers will not let you logon to a password protected site at all. Further, if you do get logged on to an open un-protected site, it will be unstable and drop your Wi-Fi connection repeatedly.

Attempts to rewrite the code directly are met with an `Access Denied` error code.

Someone at Raspian needs to immediately do an update to OS8.

Comment: What is your question exactly? You say that you have seen the problem posted many times. Could you provide some links? I have had a number of searches and unfortunately I can't find any links relating to your issue. What did the links/post, that you found, suggest, assuming that there were some suggestions, to resolve the problem? Have you contacted CanaKit or Raspbian for any support? Have you tried a later version, or updating your version? If the issue is as widespread as you say, then hopefully they are working on a fix.

Comment: As this site is not related to the Pi Foundation nor the maintainers of Raspbian pleading for someone "to immediately do an update to OS8." is wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [WiFi country code resets](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=140371&p=930465), it seems that the **Wi-Fi Country Code** menu to which you refer, by default, the version of Jessie that you have, displays Andorra, even if the actual country code is set to something different, which indeed sounds like a bug.

However, if you look at the actual config file, what country code is listed?

```
sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

If that still says Andorra, then you may be better off setting the correct code in this file manually and ignoring the GUI menu, for the time being.

I would also ensure that you have the latest update, as the issue that you have found may already be fixed:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```